# connection refused in java amazon SDK for S3 service

Tags: java, linux, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

i'm coding a command line tool to manage the S3 service. on my local machine, everything works but on the server where it should be executed, fails with the following message:

```
Error Message: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection to http://s3.amazonaws.com refused
```

i make the connection with the following code:

```
 s3  = new AmazonS3Client(credentials,clientConf);
```

clientConf only sets the protocol to HTTP, as i suspected that maybe could be a problem to connect to HTTPS but i'm having the same result.

now, the server have the following configuration:

debian 6 64 bits

LAMP installed from source

openssl installed from source

java installed from distribution packages packages

this is the network configuration:

```
    auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static

address XX.XX.XX.XX
netmask 255.255.255.255
broadcast XX.XX.XX.XX (same as address)

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static

address XX.XX.XX.XX
netmask 255.255.255.255
broadcast XX.XX.XX.XX (same as address)

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static

address XX.XX.XX.XX
netmask 255.255.255.255
broadcast XX.XX.XX.XX (same as address)

post-up route add 10.255.255.1 dev eth0
post-up route add default gw 10.255.255.1
```

wget, telnet, curl, everything works, except this, i have 3 network interfaces as i have 2 SSL and another ip for the other sites.

how i should configure the clientConf to make this work? is a java problem? a network problem? at least, how i can get more debug info? i tried to catch the `AmazonClientException` exception but doesn't work.

Thanks in advance :)

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

[This has been reported as a bug in the Amazon S3 API](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=88173). Quoth [ZachM@AWS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/profile.jspa?userID=150724):

> This appears to be a bug in the SDK. The problem is that the client
>   configuration object is shared with the Security Token Service client
>   that DynamoDB uses to establish a session, and it (unlike Dynamo)
>   doesn't accept the HTTP protocol. There are a couple workarounds:
>
> 1) Create your own instance of STSSessionCredentialsProvider and
>   provide it to your DynamoDB client, or
>
> 2) Instead of specifying the protocol in the ClientConfiguration,
>   specify it with a call to setEndpoint("http://...")
>
> We'll discuss solutions for this bug.

I would recommend using one of the workarounds for now. Good luck getting your connection to work successfully.

([Additional documentation and workarounds](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/Amazon-RDS/3604))

Comment: i tried this, but seems that doesn't work with S3, i'm still having the same problem.

Comment: @shadow_of__soul Hmn. That is a quandary, then! As you say, you have a desire for more debugging information that you can use to trace the issue. Are you able to run your client in a debugger (for example, in the debugging facilities provided by IntelliJ or Eclipse) and set a breakpoint directly before the exception fires? For that matter, what happens when you just `catch (Exception e)` (which will notably catch `RuntimeException`) when you attempt the connection? I'm sorry to go with the standard advice here, but I don't have good bounds on what you've tried yet.

Comment: the problem is that this only happen in the server, locally the code works perfectly. is there anyway to run a debugger from a command line? (i'm running the app wtih `java -jar app.jar`)

Comment: @shadow_of__soul Yes! You'll want to look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/jdb.html) for that functionality. If local or remote debugging in `jdb` isn't sufficient, I'm sure we can hash something else out that fits your needs. :)